# SSD with 64bit windows 8.1 won't boot when put in older computer

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I wanted to demonstrate to my friends the impact a faster disk can have on overall performance, but on some of these older computers (they do have 64 bit processors and sata ports however) the boot process just won't start, and on others it works like a charm, preparing devices for about 20 seconds or so before booting up. 
What is going on here? I've entered BIOS and set my SSD as the first and only boot option in all instances (I had to detach the old disks since there was only 1 sata cable in the computer every time). So it's not an issue of the motherboard 'acknowledging' the SSD, but maybe something else. Could it have something to do with the state of NTFS and Windows 8.x's quick reboot options? Maybe it didn't do a complete shutdown when I detached it from my PC.

Ideas? 2 Cpu-z images coming up.. (two non-working and one working, soon)

First non-working:
[image: This is a snapshot of the first computer]

Second non-working:
[image: This is a snapshot of the second computer]

This is a working pc:
[image: This is a snapshot of the first working computer]

Comment: Without more specific information about the computer we wouldn't be able to say the reason WHY it wasn't able to boot there are far to many possible reasons.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, but it's more than one computer. I tried this on two laptops as well. I thought maybe there was a backwards compatibility issue, something SATA related or something straightforward that could explain why it happens on multiple occasions.

Comment: SATA I drives can work on SATA III ports.  SATA III drives can work on SATA I ports.  SATA is has full backwards capability.

Comment: @Ramhound I'll post the cpu-z screenshots from two computers, will that help?

Comment: No; Not Really.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just pulling out the drive from your computer and putting it into their computer, you're going to have a bad time. The real compatibility test would to be putting a clean SSD into their system, and installing the OS from scratch on their system.

I had an older (2008) Thinkpad T400 that I put an Crucial M4 SSD into and it had a lot of problems initially. While it'd recognize the drive, the was very flaky about booting sometimes and not others. It ended up being a BIOS issue, so I wouldn't rule out making sure your friend's PC is on the latest version for that board.

Comment: Dang, just when i thought things were becoming interchangable. Thanks for the post, I'll definitely try it out eventually.

Answer (score 0):

The drivers configured with win 8.1 differ with hardware. Use a Linux live CD or USB to boot and test performance. Try Netrunner OS for this. It's a loaded OS, similar to real life use.

Comment: The drivers differ, true, but I thought that's what the `preparing devices` pre-loading was meant to handle, which it DOES, on some computers. This is what puzzles me so much.

Answer (score 0):

I'll need to put in more research time before accepting my own answer, but I thought I'd post what I think it is.
It basically boils down to whether the motherboard is [UEFI-compliant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface). This would explain, to a certain degree, why I never have issues when I take my SSD from my home PC to work- both are relatively modern PCs. The one working PC snapshot I posted in my question is my work PC, the one I'm typing on right, now, using the SSD in question!

It would be great if someone would correct me if I'm wrong, or confirm my suspicions.